# Action Script 3 Health Bar Issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am new to AS3 and i am currently trying to add dynamic health into my code.
Here is the code i have based on the dynamic health.

```
var currentHealth:int = 5000;
var totalHealth:int = 10000;
//Dynamic health
var healthPack:medipack = new medipack();
healthPack.width = 30;
healthPack.height = 30;
healthPack.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
healthPack.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
stage.addChild(healthPack);
```

and:

```
//Display current health
health.bar.width = 300 * (currentHealth / totalHealth);
currentHealth -= 1;

//detecting collision with health
if (stage.contains(healthPack))
{
    if (player_mc.hitTestObject(healthPack))
        {
            currentHealth += 5000;
            healthPack.parent.removeChild(healthPack);
        }
}
```

My Current Symbols i Have in my library associated with health are:

HealthBarBg (has an instance name of bar) and is an instance of healthBar
healthBar
and medipack

Whenever i run this code i get the error of:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 91, Column 2    1120: Access of undefined property healthBar.
```

Im Not Sure what i've done wrong, any help is appriciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have `healthBar` defined. Why do you show code where the `healthBar` is not in?

Comment: @putvande Thanks, sorry was having a big of a blonde moment. Much Appreciated.

Comment: If the above comment is the answer, the comment should be created as an answer and accepted so this question is marked as answered in the current questions queue.